# Does primefaces work with facelets?

Tags: java, jsf-2, primefaces, facelets

I'm building a Java web App using JSF 2.0 running on a tomcat server. And i'm using `facelets1.1.10` .I've recently seen what primefaces can do and I'm very impressed by it. So i'd like to add primefaces into my web project.

I downloaded the `primefaces3.2.jar` from the website and added it to my project lib folder ( where I keep all the jars). and added it to my build path. but when test it out to see if the primefaces worked I get the following error:

> SEVERE: Error Loading Library:
>   jar:file:/C:/tomcat/wtpwebapps/miloWeb/WEB-INF/lib/primefaces-3.2.jar!/META-INF/primefaces-p.taglib.xml
>   java.io.IOException: Error parsing
>   [jar:file:/C:/tomcat/wtpwebapps/miloWeb/WEB-INF/lib/primefaces-3.2.jar!/META-INF/primefaces-p.taglib.xml]:
>     at
>   com.sun.facelets.compiler.TagLibraryConfig.create(TagLibraryConfig.java:397)
>     at
>   com.sun.facelets.compiler.TagLibraryConfig.loadImplicit(TagLibraryConfig.java:418)
>     at com.sun.facelets.compiler.Compiler.initialize(Compiler.java:86)
>     at com.sun.facelets.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:103)    at
>   com.sun.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletFactory.createFacelet(DefaultFaceletFactory.java:192)
>     at
>   com.sun.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletFactory.getFacelet(DefaultFaceletFactory.java:141)
>     at
>   com.sun.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletFactory.getFacelet(DefaultFaceletFactory.java:93)
>     at
>   com.sun.facelets.FaceletViewHandler.buildView(FaceletViewHandler.java:503)
>     at
>   com.sun.facelets.FaceletViewHandler.renderView(FaceletViewHandler.java:553)
>     at
>   com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:110)
>     at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:100)    at
>   com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139)
>     at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:266)   at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:304)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
>     at
>   org.apache.myfaces.webapp.filter.ExtensionsFilter.doFilter(ExtensionsFilter.java:349)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:242)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:240)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:203)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:164)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:108)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:558)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:379)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:242)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:259)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:237)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:281)
>     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown
>   Source)   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown
>   Source)   at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) Caused by:
>   org.xml.sax.SAXException: Error Handling
>   [jar:file:/C:/tomcat/wtpwebapps/miloWeb/WEB-INF/lib/primefaces-3.2.jar!/META-INF/primefaces-p.taglib.xml@5,17]
>     at
>   com.sun.facelets.compiler.TagLibraryConfig$LibraryHandler.error(TagLibraryConfig.java:363)
>     at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.error(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.rootElementSpecified(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.handleStartElement(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.startElement(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$ContentDriver.scanRootElementHook(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$PrologDriver.next(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown
>   Source)   at javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)    at
>   javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)     at
>   com.sun.facelets.compiler.TagLibraryConfig.create(TagLibraryConfig.java:394)
>     ... 31 more

What does that mean? what do I have to do in order to keep facelets and add primefaces?

Comment: Yes it is working with facelets... remove the facelets1.1.10 from your project and try again... take a look at this detailed answer... http://stackoverflow.com/a/4532870/617373

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it is working with Facelets...(Facelets 2.0)

Take a look at this detailed answer by **BalusC** [Migrating from JSF 1.2 to JSF 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4441713/migrating-from-jsf-1-2-to-jsf-2-0/4532870#4532870)

Some Snippet from  Original **BalusC** answer...

### Facelets 1.x to Facelets 2.0

If you're using **Facelets 1.x** as view technology and want to use the JSF 2.0 supplied **Facelets 2.0**, then you need to do the following additional steps:

- Remove Facelets 1.x JAR from `/WEB-INF/lib`.
- Remove Facelets 1.x `FaceletViewHandler` from `faces-config.xml`.
- Any custom `FaceletViewHandler` implementation needs to be updated to extend [`ViewHandlerWrapper`][2] instead.
- Not necessary, but just for cleanup, remove any Facelets 1.x related `<context-param>` values from `web.xml` which are already default in Facelets 2.0, like the `javax.faces.DEFAULT_SUFFIX` with value of `*.xhtml`.
- Update root declaration of existing Facelet taglib XML's to comply Facelets 2.0.

  ```xml
  <facelet-taglib 
      xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-facelettaglibrary_2_0.xsd"
      version="2.0">
  ```

Comment: That last part of updating the root declaration of existing facelet taglib, where is that? I searched all my files and don't find any <facelet-taglib

Comment: I think it is somehow related to custom components.... http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/custom-tags-in-jsf-2-0/ and I guess you don't have one in your project...

Comment: I tried those changes and I get a class not found error. do I need to add a facelets 2.0 jar?

Comment: no , no such thing as far as i know , edit your question and post the stack trace... or some details

Comment: I actually already asked that here  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9998524/migrating-to-facelets-2-0-from-facelets-1-x can you please take a look to see if anything looks fishy?

Comment: you already got an answer over there... include jstl-1.2.jar.... seems that it will solve the new issue over there...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9652/discussion-between-myy-and-daniel)

Comment: I don't believe I ever actually Thank you. I greatly appreciate the time, I finally fixed it, and I believe I am running fine now. =)

Answer (score 0):

Remove `view-hander` config from your `faces-config.xml`

[Here](http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=862#p3852) is a similar problem and its solution at primefaces forum.